# Use value only when promise resolves

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have an `app` which consists of `services` that are registered `async`.

First time before I use `app` I want app to register all `services`. I would want to somehow return a `Promise` and only `then` return specific service I need.

```
export function app() {
  if (instance) return instance;
  instance = express(feathers());

  ORM.default.then((data) => {
    setupServices();
    instance.configure(initServices);
    return instance; //this is needed before service usage
  });
  return instance;
}

export function service(name) {
  return app().service(name);
}
```

Other file:

```
import { service } from '../app';

const teamService = service('team');
```

At the moment teamService is `null`, as service register async and are not registered first time I import it.

Comment: You cannot wait before returning. You have to return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to return the promise directly

```
return ORM.default.then((data) => {
    setupServices();
    instance.configure(initServices);
    return instance; //this is needed before service usage
});
```

so that you can use `app.then( ... )`

Comment: But then I will have to resolve a promise with `service()` function too and where I use service I will have to use `.then` is that right?

Comment: Actually I dont know if you really need the service(part) it just calls another function. If you use app directly you will be able to use `instance.service(name)` in the `then` part.